# Why identity === operator isn't available in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I was just eager to know, **Why identity === operator isn't available in c#?.** Is there any reason that isn't available. **What is the equalant to === operator in c#?**
Because I saw in a place that identity operator === is faster that equal == operator.
Because == operator change the datatype temporarily.

**Update:** Difference between `===` and `==` operator.
=== basically doesn't convert the two variable into temporarily data type while == equal temporarily convert the data type of converted variables

Comment: It doesn't exist because either no one requested it or it it's not important enough to spend the time to implement (or both).  What would you expect that operator to do?

Comment: I don't see why this question needs to be down voted...

Comment: You dont need === because c# is strictly typed. Meaning your not going to compare variables of two data types without first converting them to a common type.

Comment: I am still confused, why this question is down voted. please provide any reason

Comment: Why 6 downvotes? Coming from JavaScript, it's not that bad a question. Except for the "where I can use it?" maybe.

Comment: a person who has 182k voting and answered me. So, I think this wont be a joke

Comment: Explain why you need it in C#.

Comment: that is my question. Why I don't need it in c#?

Comment: The close reason is not constructive, it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) exists.

Because value types override equality.

Because C#, unlike JavaScript doesn't have "truthy" and "falsy" values and the implicit conversions are well defined.

In short, it doesn't exist because it is not needed in C#, unlike JavaScript.

Comment: I am wondering, a person who has 182k answered me and people still give me down voting

Comment: @DotNetDreamer - Please explain what the two have to do with each other?

Comment: @Oded `ReferenceEquals` is not equivilent to `===`.

Comment: @DotNetDreamer Because it's a good answer to a poor question.

Comment: @Matthew - Of course not. I don't imply it does. I also give other reasons for why `===` doesn't exist in C#.

Comment: @Oded I am wondering how you relate `ReferenceEquals` to `===`.

Comment: can you elaborate it alittle bit more.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to PHP / javascript being a dynamic typed language while C-Sharp is static typed.

For example (in PHP)

```
if (5 == '5') ... // is true
if (5 === '5') ... // is false
```

While in C#

```
if (5 == '5') ... // compile error, incompatible types
```

**EDIT**

To elaborate, a lot of types do not have an implicit conversion (ie strings vs ints), which results in a compile error, but for those cases where there is an implicit conversion (ints vs floats), to do a similar type of comparison you can do.

```
float x = 1.0f;
int y = 1;

if (x == y) ... // is true
if (x == y && x.GetType() == y.GetType()) ... // is false
```

Comment: "Weakly typed" != "dynamically typed".  `==` between different types could actually cause all kinds of breakage in a weakly typed language.  In C, for example, you might be comparing a pointer with a number.

Comment: @cHao you're right, updating...